# 404 in downloading a file using <iframe> and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I am using a **iframe** to download an excel file from the server through an AJAX request.Whenever a button is clicked the server creates an excel file  **in about half a minute** and sends the url back to the client.I am setting the value of the url in the **"src"** attribute of the **iframe**

```
$("#ExportExcelFrame").attr('src', url);
```

The client throws a 404 error even though the file exist and could be accessed from the generated URL.

Whenever I hard code the file name (using file name of some pre-exiting file) to eliminate the processing delay the set up works and the excel file is downloaded.

I have tried to change the timeout of ajax request to no avail

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    timeout: 120000 //Time in milliseconds

});
```

Any suggestions will be hugely appreciated.

The ajax call

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Controller',
                data: {type: param, StartDate: StartDate, EndDate: EndDate, DateType:dateType,ResEstmBean: JSON.stringify(ResourceEstmBean)},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $.blockUI({message: message, css: messageCss});
                },
                success: function (data)
                {


                        var fileName = data;

                        var url = "http://localhost:8080/WebApp/" + fileName;


                        $("#ExportExcelFrame").attr('src', url);

                        $.unblockUI();
                },
                        timeout: 300000,
                        error: function () {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        showErrorAlert();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you setting the `src` of the iframe as part of the AJAX success function?

Comment: @sideroxylon : ya."ExportExcelFrame" is the id of iframe.It is working fine when I m hard coding a file name(url ) generated by the servlet to avoid processing time.

Comment: OK.  It just looked like the code was trying to populate the iframe before it had received the URL of the excel file - but if you are injecting the src as part of the success function (after the AJAX process has completed), then that's not it.  Can you post your AJAX function?

Comment: @sideroxylon:I have added the ajax call code

Comment: When I have inspected the  iframe in the browser, the "src" attribute was populated with correct value of url.

Comment: Try changing `var url = "http://localhost:8080/WebApp/" + fileName;` to `var url = "/WebApp/" + fileName;` - this assumes it's on the same computer as your iframe.  `localhost` for an iframe src won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the attribute after 2 secs

```
setTimeout(function () {$("#ExportExcelFrame").attr('src', url)}, 2000);
```

Its working now.